# SQL Regex Which Can Search Combinations Of A String

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, search

I have a column in a MySQL table which has values that look like variations of the following:

`100% Cot 40sx40s 132x72 696-Red Spark - PDM#100033-56"`

Now, I want to provide a search filter to users where they can type in snippets of this string (or variations of snippets of this string) and get relevant results.

For instance, they could type '40sx40s' and they would get all results which include that snippet. I know that this is easily solved using a `REGEX` query in `SQL`.

However, there is no standard format for the way the strings are entered

1. In some of the values, the `x` in the `40sx40s` could be replaced by `*`
2. In some of the values, there might not be any `s` in the `40sx40s`. It could just be `40x40`
3. In some of the values, there might be spaces between the numbers, the letters and the symbols like so: `40 s x 40 s`.
4. In some of the values, the `132x72` is replaced by `132/72`.
5. The `Cot` which stands for cotton might be replaced by `Ctn` or even `cotton`
6. The user could combine multiple search terms in a different order from how they appear in the string.
   For example running the search: `40x40 100%ctn red` should result in the string at the top being one of the values returned.

In all of the cases above, the variations are just a user entry accident and they all reference the same thing.

I know most modern search engines perform searches like this where they are able to replace misspelled search terms with accurate ones or at least understand that they both reference the same thing.

What I want to understand is whether solving this problem is a simple procedure that a small development team can implement or whether solving this problem is so complicated that it is better to outsource to a service like [algolia](https://www.algolia.com/).

Comment: This is a hard problem to solve.  I would recommend parsing the string before it goes into the database and putting it in a canonical format.  Then do the searches on that version and teach users what that version is.

Comment: Could you give me a simple example of what you mean by parsing the string into a canonical format?

Comment: . . I mean fixing all the issues you bring up, so each string is in a "standard" format.

Comment: Would this imply that they also have to enter these strings into the DB in a specific format? Or that they would only have to enter the search term in a specific format, and I would then use that format to search for all variations?